# What happens when a pouchDB local database reach the device's storage limit?

Tags: javascript, storage, indexeddb, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB to create a local database (based on indexeddb).

I'd like to know **what actually happens when we are reaching the limit of available storage of a browser?**

Does PouchBD silently fail or does it throw a clear error?
Or maybe it is the browser that pops an alert?

I would like to simulate this use case but can't found a way to do so without having to manually add 16Go of data in my browser.